# Unable to display data from textfile into UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am unable to display the text from the Textfile.txt. I was able to succesfully print the data on console but not on the UITextView.Thanks

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mytextview: UITextView!    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let path = "/Users/jack/textfile.txt"

    do {
        var data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path,
                                encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)


        print(data)
    }catch {
        //handle error
        print(error)
    }

    mytextview.text = Data() as? String

}
```

Comment: `mytextview.text = Data() as? String` What is that supposed to do? What do you think it does, or what did you write it? Clearly there is an issue on this line. It doesn't make sense at all. Doesn't XCode throws you a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
let path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myText", ofType: "txt")!   

do {
     var data = try String(contentsOfFile: path,encoding:.utf8)

     mytextview.text = data 
}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Why `NSString`?

Comment: use 'mytextview.text = data as String'

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let path = "/Users/jack/textfile.txt"

    do {
        var data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path,
                                encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)

        mytextview.text = data // change here
        print(data)
    }catch {
        //handle error
        print(error)
    }
    mytextview.text = Data() as? String
}
```